# in php create a selection in option list from csv file

Tags: php, csv, html-select

i have a csv file that creates a select option list.

after submit the selected option os cleared. how can i keep the option in the selection ?

CSV FILE:

```
"Agusta Westland 109s",A109,2,Turbine,IFR,7,155,4,250,2500
"Bell 427",B427,2,Turbine,VFR,7,140,5,200,2000
"Eurocopter AS355 Ecureuil",Squirrel,2,Turbine,VFR,5,120,5,180,1800
"Eurocopter EC130 B4",EC130,1,Turbine,VFR,6,120,4,140,2500
"Robinson R22",R22,1,Piston,VFR,1,90,8,50,300
"Robinson R44 Raven 2",R44,1,Piston,VFR,3,110,6,75,1100
```

PHP CODE:

```html
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
if (!file_exists('types.csv')) {
    exit("Your Types file doesn't exist");
} else {
 $types = array_map('str_getcsv', file('types.csv'));
 $aircraftTitles = array("Aircraft");
 echo "<table class='table'>";
 echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($aircraftTitles as $row){  
     echo "<th>".$row."</th>";
 }
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "<tr>";
 //select type 
 echo "<td><select name = 'type'>";
 echo "<option value='".null."'>Select Aircraft Type</option>";
    foreach ($types as $row){ 
     echo "<option value='".$row[1].",".$row[6].",".$row[7].",".$row[8]."'>".$row[1]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
```

thanks very much for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the value from the $_POST across the values of the array.  If it matches, select as the selected option.  If it does not match then just show the option.

Like this:

```
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
if (!file_exists('types.csv')) {
    exit("Your Types file doesn't exist");
} else {
    $types = array_map('str_getcsv', file('types.csv'));

    $aircraftTitles = array("Aircraft");
    echo "<table class='table'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($aircraftTitles as $row){
        echo "<th>".$row."</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    //select type
    echo "<td><select name = 'type'>";
    echo "<option value='" . null . "'>Select Aircraft Type</option>";

    foreach($types as $row) {

          $str = $row[1]. "," .$row[6] . "," . $row[7] . "," .$row[8];
          if($_POST['type'] == $str) {

            echo  '<option value="' . $str . '"' . ' selected="selected"' . '>' . $row[1] . '</option>';

          }else {

            echo  '<option value="' . $str . '">' . $row[1] . '</option>';

          }

     }

    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
echo "</table>";

}
```